# How can I create two list columns beside a wrapfigure enviroment?

Tags: tables, itemize, wrapfigure

I've been playing around with the wrapfigure package and I would really like to create a list to the right of it.
That I have figured out, but things got complicated when I wanted a second list right beside my first list.
I tried minipages but that disrupts my wrapfigure.
Now my issue is, that there is this very akward clear space above my tikz graphics and it's what i am trying to resolve.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

%colors
    \definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{004AAD}
    \definecolor{purple}{HTML}{8C52FF}
    \definecolor{darkpurple}{HTML}{6C0EAD}
    \definecolor{pink}{HTML}{FF66C4}
    \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{38B6FF}
    \definecolor{green}{HTML}{4FCD91}

%----------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\section*{Einführung in die Elektrostatik} 
Zwei Objekte, die geladen sind, wirken Kräfte aufeinander aus. Diese Objekte nennen wir Elektrische Ladungen.
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill [pink] (0,0) circle [radius=0.5] node [black]{$+1e$};
        \fill [lightgray] (1.5,0) circle [radius=0.5] node [black]{$0e$};
        \fill [darkblue] (3,0) circle [radius=0.15] node [black, right] {\ $ -1e$};
         
    \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption*{}
\end{wrapfigure}
\hspace{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.45\linewidth}p{0.45\linewidth}@{}}
    \textbf{- Träger:}
    \begin{itemize}[itemsep=1pt]
        \item Elektronen
        \item negative Ione ($e^- > p$)
    \end{itemize} &
    \textbf{+ Träger:}
    \begin{itemize}[itemsep=1pt]
        \item Nucleus
        \item positive Ione ($e^- < p$)
    \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

Comment: What about to use of three column table, where in the fists is image, and other two your lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

%colors
    \definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{004AAD}
    \definecolor{purple}{HTML}{8C52FF}
    \definecolor{darkpurple}{HTML}{6C0EAD}
    \definecolor{pink}{HTML}{FF66C4}
    \definecolor{blue}{HTML}{38B6FF}
    \definecolor{green}{HTML}{4FCD91}

%----------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\section*{Einführung in die Elektrostatik}
Zwei Objekte, die geladen sind, wirken Kräfte aufeinander aus. Diese Objekte nennen wir Elektrische Ladungen.

\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X X[h]X[h]}, 
             stretch=-1,
              measure = vbox,
              rowsep  =5 pt
             }   
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [pink]        (0.0,0) circle [radius=0.5] node [black]{$+1e$};
    \fill [lightgray]   (1.5,0) circle [radius=0.5] node [black]{$0e$};
    \fill [darkblue]    (3.0,0) circle [radius=0.15] node [black, right] {\ $ -1e$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\captionof{figure}{caption}
    &   \textbf{$-$ Träger:}
        \begin{itemize}[itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*]
    \item Elektronen
    \item negative Ione ($e^- > p$)
        \end{itemize} 
        &   \textbf{+ Träger:}
            \begin{itemize}[itemsep=1pt, leftmargin=*]
        \item Nucleus
        \item positive Ione ($e^- < p$)
            \end{itemize}
\end{tblr}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Edit:

- As I said in comment, for what you try to achieve, is better and simpler collect image and lists in three column table
- For table I would select `tblr` of `tabularray` package, for lists `enumitem` and for eventual caption (so far you nit use it) `caption` package:
- `tabularray`

  - is relative new, versatile and powerful package for typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3
  - it has intuitive, easy to learn syntax combining column types know from `tabular` and `tabularx` like `c`, `l`, `r`, `p`, `m`,`b` and `X` which can be used in any combination. To the are added new types as `h` for align at top of cells and `f` for align at foot of cells.
  - columns and rows can be in `math` or `dmath` mode
  - it enable to define text shapes in families for rows too
  - for other, numerus features (like emulating threeparttable, long tables, etc.) see package documentation
- `enumitem` enables simple design `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description` lists, for details see package documentation
- of course, instead of `tblr` you may also use `tabular` with `p` columns or `tabularx` with `X` columns, but, to my opinion, with less simple and elegant code.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. May I know what the tblr environment does and when it's best to use it?

Comment: @434dx, `zblr` table is defined in `tabularray` package. It is very versatile and powerful package for typeset tabulars and arrays with LaTeX3. For detaičs see package documentation. To answer I will add some explanation.